# To Change Width of a Particular Track in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, layout, design-rules

I am working on a PCB layout in Altium 23. The default track width in my PCB is 8 mils. However, I want to change the width of a couple of components. For instance, I want the width of the track VCC to be 60 mils for capacitor C1 only.

[image: This is the default track width rule]

This is the default track width rule.

I have added a new rule, Width_1 for the required track width as shown below:
[image: This is the Rule that I added for this particular track.]

I have set the priority of the new rule to be higher. However, Altium is still forcing the tracks to be of 8 mils.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: You can do so from the properties of the track